# Cross-platform library: how to organize project?

Tags: libraries, visual-studio, project-structure, cross-platform, msbuild

Our company develops and sells a cross-platform C++ library. We distribute **binary only** versions for Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, iOS, Android, etc. The only source code the customers get is the header files with the class interfaces. Our IDE is Visual Studio; we're very glad it now supports cross-compilation out-of-the-box (clang! remote control of a Mac with XCode! Ability to call older versions of the compiler! Makes our lives much easier). We try to build all the versions at the same time on the same build machine (which calls out to a Mac to do the iOS and Mac OS X ports). Most customers are on Windows and just get the libraries for recent Visual C++, but some customers get the works.

The code itself is the same between platforms.

However, not all of our customers are on the latest version of Visual Studio -- some of them are using versions as far back as 2005. While we are trying to encourage them to move to a newer version, we still have to support the old ones if they find a bug.

This leads to a proliferation of product configurations: (Debug/Release) * (Static library/Shared Library) * (Platform) * (x86/x64/ARM) * (Compiler version)

most of which are very similar to each other, but with some differences.

I was studying MSBuild and playing around with the `.vcxproj` file but it still seems extremely complicated (and Visual Studio chokes on any `.vcxproj` with anything more than a bare minimum of tweaks).

The way we used to deal with this was to manually tweak the project each time we were doing a new build. That is obviously unsustainable.

I was assigned to bring the project up-to-date, and I initially created a bunch of new configurations, corresponding to that absurd cross product I mentioned above. I think that makes for 40 configurations. Ugh. But aside from the management headache, I didn't always make the necessary project settings changes when copying from (say) x86 to x64. So some of the new configurations didn't build when I did a batch build.

In order to stop this happening again, I created a bunch of new user macros in the project file (probably should have been in the `.props` file referenced in the

```
<ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release-2013|Win32'"
 Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props"
     Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')"
     Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)Microsoft.CPP.UpgradeFromVC60.props" />  
</ImportGroup>
```

I guess) and made sure that all the project configurations were **the same** and that the changes between each of them were just made in the user macros. But that's getting unwieldy too, and pulling down a menu of 40 things to select the right thing to build, plus then having to go into the right folder and pick out the relevant files, also seems error prone.

So my question is: How can I make this more automatic and not require so much thought? Do people creating a cross-platform library really work with 40+ configurations in their project? How are some ways people handle this in real life -- or at least set things up so they don't make so many mistakes?

Comment: Hi downvoter. I'm pretty sure this is a question that's on-topic for se.se because it's about project management. I do refer to the tools that I'm using but that's only as reference. The same questions would apply if I were using `make`.

Comment: Your question as stated is far too broad: "How should I deal with this?" You need to narrow down your question for this forum.

Comment: Some questions: How is this distributed? I'm guessing not as source. Do you supply all the different types of libraries for each platform separately? If so, do you build, for example, all the Windows ones at once on a single machine, or are they all built on different machines and then packaged together? Does every customer get every version?

Comment: @BobDalgleish Question updated. Key question is how to not make so many errors managing this many different configurations.

Comment: @user1118321 Question updated. Binary + headers. Most frequent customers are Windows x86 only, next most frequent Windows x86+x64, some customers get the works. All built on one machine then packaged together as per each customer's license.

Answer (score 2):

In a past project of mine, I had to deal with a very large amount of configurations, just like you. In the end, I dropped VisualStudio's IDE configuration management in favor of a scripted one (Premake in my case). This lets me generate a solution with just the configurations I want to use (or even all at the same time), just by letting the scripted system cross-combining the different options for me. For instance, I can tell "build me a solution for VS2013 x64, VS2013 x86, VS2015 x64 and Linux x64, for both 'debug' and 'release'".

It's not as nice as having it all in the IDE, but lets me have a fine control of every option without going insane every time I have to change a setting.